# Add column name to row based on max value within that row in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of FEMA flood risk 2.0 data. Each column name indicates how much a home owner's monthly flood insurance premimums will change. Each row contains a `float` representing the percentage of homes within that Zip Code will have their premimums adjusted according to the corresponding column name. Like so:

```
Col1       Col2               Col3                   Col4
Zip Code   < -$100        -$100 to -$90          -$90 to -$80
33010      .0194              .0036                  .0040 
33138      .0568              .0082                  .0109
33141      .0101              .0008                  .0019
```

I want to add a column where each row contains the name of the column that had the highest value for each row. My output should be:

```
 Col1       Col2               Col3                   Col4        Col5
Zip Code   < -$100        -$100 to -$90          -$90 to -$80    common_price_change
33010      .0194              .0036                  .0040        <-$100
33138      .0568              .1082                  .0109        -$100 to -$90
33141      .0101              .0008                  .0319        -$90 to -$80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `df.idxmax()` method to get what you want.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'zip_code':['zip1','zip2','zip3'],
              'col1':[0,1,3],
              'col2':[3,2,1],
              'col3':[4,0,2]
              })

df['max_col'] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].idxmax(axis=1)
df
```

The `max_col` is using `idxmax` to get the column name with the highest value.